# ASP Handler not returning error message to ajax call on hosted environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, error-handling

I have a Handler which is called by ajax call, and i am returning error from Stored Procedure SQL

Below is my ajax call

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Handlers/MyHandlerCall.ashx?QueCtrlType=1"
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('ok')
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert(e.responseText) // Here i want error message from my Stored Procedure
                    }
                })
```

Here is my MyHandlerCall.ashx

```
try
        {
            DataTable dt = //Database Call and return DataTable which is working fine
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                context.Response.Write('ok');
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            context.Response.Write(ex.Message);  // Passing error which works locally very fine but not on my hosted environment


        }
```

My SQL SP returning error

```
IF (1)  
BEGIN  
 RAISERROR('Invalid Call',16,1)  
 RETURN  
END
```

Its returning Proper error Message locally but on hosted environment it is throwing Internal Server Error and not my Sp message

Comment: Given that it works locally but not on your hosted server then it appears this is a configuration problem with your host. You need to check what the error is and debug it. Given the lack of information you've given us, no one here can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your server is showing the default Error Messages 
If you want to show the Custom Messages then write below code

```
        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        context.Response.Write('Message');
```

For IIS7+

Answer (score 0):

`error` callback will be executed in case of ajax error. In your case, the ajax call is executed successfully and returns a response that contains an error. So, you have to check for this error inside your success callback:

**ASP.NET**

```
catch (Exception ex)
{            
   context.Response.Write(string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message));
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
   url: "Handlers/MyHandlerCall.ashx?QueCtrlType=1"
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function (data) {
      if (data.indexOf('Error') === 0) {
         // Handle the SQL error
      } else {
         alert('ok');
      }
   },
   error: function (e) {
      alert(e.responseText)
   }
  })
```